# IntelliJ commit 50-character line length reminder

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When committing a change on the IntelliJ platform, is there a way to have it check that the first line of the commit message does not exceed the 50-character length limit?

Right now, I'm usually checking this manually, with the position indicator in the lower right corner of the main IDE window (the one that is formatted as `line:character`). However that indicator is sometimes hidden by other tool windows, and requires me to have the cursor at the end of the first line. Is there some setting I can enable or some plugin I can install to have the IDE check this for me?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For anyone still interested in this: I've come across a new setting which does allow what I initially wanted, in a settings group called 'Commit Dialog'.

[image: Commit dialog limit]

You can now have it warn you about a long subject line right in the dialog, without needing the visual aid of a delimiter!

Answer (score 22):

I know this question is a bit old (almost 4 years at the time of my posting), and about IntelliJ, but on **PyCharm 2020.2** this setting has been made more granular & universal.

[image: Limit for commit message line length]

[image: Limit for commit subject line length]

It's now in **Version Control > Commit**, and part of the "Commit message inspections", and you can set different line lengths for the body and the subject.

Comment: Same for newer versions of IntelliJ! This is the best answer in 2022.

Comment: This also highlights the excess text as you type. For me it took about ten minutes before that feature started working.

Answer (score 21):

For newer IntelliJ versions (at least 2017 and above) read [the (self-)answer of @gandreadis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45563628/8340320).

---

In older IntelliJ version you can set *Right margin* for commit messages to 50 characters in *Settings/Version Control*.

[image]

Then the commit message input should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Cool, after years of using IntelliJ I finally discover that there's a setting for this :D

Comment: I just updated to 2019.3.1 from an older version and am no longer seeing the right margin indicator, or a place to set it in the preferences.  Any idea if it's moved?

Comment: @M.Justin I'm using (among others) WebStorm 2019.3.1 (should be the same for all IntelliJ-based products). I could re-enable the highlighting by activating the corresponding inspection `Limit body line` at `Settings` > `Version Control` > `Commit Dialog`. If you do so and select one of the inspections, further options will be shown on the right (including one option where you can set the allowed number of characters). That's also what @gandreadis wrote as answer (today, you also have an additional option _Show right margin_ in the dialog).

Comment: Cool, we can limit subject line too

Comment: Android Studio 4.0.0 seems to have removed this useful feature. The other answer's feature is still available though, just the right margin bar was removed.